# Remove text from address bar

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to remove text displayed in the address bar without redirecting the page? For instance, if the address is:

http://example.com/?page=main

Can I get the server to change the displayed text to:

http://example.com/main

Will this affect SEO? I've researched htaccess, but can't find anything useful.

I'd also like to be able to enter:

http://example.com/main

And for users to reach the page displayed here, with the above text:

http://example.com/?page=main

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to re-research .htaccess files: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```